# Problem adding a custom REL tag handler

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, java

We have implemented a REL tag handler for our Tridion 2011 content delivery server. The REL tag handler has to do some specific functionality when resolving component & page links.

This REL handler is working as it should when using some hardcoded values, but from the moment we include a call to another class responsible to get these values from a properties file (another piece of code from the customer's project), IIS throws an error when the REL handler is called.

The problem is this error is not very clear - it just states something went wrong and we need to check the server logs (but the logs don't show anything that might point us to the right direction).

We also tried to add some custom logging to the handler to see what is going wrong, but our log statements don't show up (logback.xml is set to DEBUG).

There is most likely an error with the propertyreader class, but it's hard to pin-point the problem without knowing the exact error.

Does anybody know how to get logging from a custom REL handler working, or even how to debug such a handler from Eclipse ?

Comment: Hi Harald, with regards the comment " it just states something went wrong and we need to check the server logs (but the logs don't show anything that might point us to the right direction)." is it possible to add the log message. and when you refer the 'the propertyreader class' perhaps it would be useful to add this also?

Answer (score 2):

After further inspection to the propertyreader class, and our dev setup, we noted that this class is using the log4j library, but the jar file for this library were not deployed to our content delivery environment. This caused the issue, and once this jar file is copied to our lib folder the system is working properly now.

Howver, if anybody knows what needs to be done to enable logging to the standard tridion logs (cd_core.log etc), it would be nice to know.

Comment: You may want to ask this as a separate question, as it changes the scope of the answers...

Comment: Interesting follow up question. I posted it in a new question: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3233/what-needs-to-be-done-to-enable-logging-to-the-standard-tridion-content-delivery